# finding a row index and column index value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find a index of row, by giving definite column number.

```
import pandas as pd
list1=[['a1','a2','a3'],['b1','b2','b3'],['c1','c2','c3']]
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
```

[image]

how can I find it?

Comment: Why does it return index 1 and not 0 or 2? There two unknowns in your equation.

Comment: ```df.loc[df[1]=="b2"].index[0]```. working on ur images posted

Comment: Thanks in advance. I tried  sammywemmy's solution, it is workable.   but I doubt that why it is index[0], not index[1]?
For above picture, vice versus, if I want to giving "row number=1", return "column=1", how can I program  it?

Answer (score 0):

To get it, you have to use iloc in the following way:

```
print(df.iloc[1][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .iloc attribute. Below is an example:

```
  df.iloc[1,2]
```

This gets the object at row 1 and column 2.

You can even splice using a colon. Example:

```
  df.iloc[2:5 , 3:8]
```

This gets all the elements from rows 2 to 5 and 3 to 8.

More information on iloc can be found here:

https://thispointer.com/select-rows-columns-by-name-or-index-in-dataframe-using-loc-iloc-python-pandas/

Hope this helps